# Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined , angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, minimongo, meteor-publications

I am using angular-meteor for my project. When I removed 'autopublish' and added publish methods for my collections, I am getting a following error in console, when I am trying to fetch any data.

```
Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
at Object.addedAt (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular-meteor-data.js?36dfe4bee5b3da21eaa0d9bc0366addac4788a1a:2191:24)
at observeChangesCallbacks.addedBefore (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?cdf1a26cf7719fa9471a8017c3defd5aea812727:3623:28)
at Object.self.applyChange.addedBefore (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?cdf1a26cf7719fa9471a8017c3defd5aea812727:3560:56)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?cdf1a26cf7719fa9471a8017c3defd5aea812727:407:13
at _.extend.runTask (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:685:11)
at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:713:10)
at _.extend.drain (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:721:12)
at LocalCollection.insert (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?cdf1a26cf7719fa9471a8017c3defd5aea812727:615:22)
at Object.self._connection.registerStore.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?69942a86515ec397dfd8cbb0a151a0eefdd9560d:250:28)
at Object.store.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3555:48)
```

I have been trying to solve this since a long time, but couldn't find any solutions.

My Controller code:

```
  controllerAs: 'dash',
  controller: function($scope, $reactive, $state) {
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);
     this.subscribe('sheets');
     this.helpers({
            sheets: () => {
              return Sheets.find({});
            }
          });
  }
}
```

and publish code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.publish("sheets", function () {
return Sheets.find({});
 });
}
```

I am not getting error when I add 'autopublish' to the project

Comment: This link might interest you. https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1265